# How to call a method on an object while it is being animated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am calling a method on an object on TouchUpInside. The first time the object is tapped, its background color will be animated. If I try to quickly tap the object again while it is fading in, the method is not being called.

Here is where I add the elementSelect action:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self addTarget:self action: @selector(elementSelect) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.amount = 0;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is the elementSelect method itself:

```
- (void)elementSelect {
    NSLog(@"Element Selected");
    if (![[AppDataObject sharedInstance].currentElementArray containsObject:self]) {
        [[AppDataObject sharedInstance].currentElementArray addObject:self];
        self.amount = 1;
    } else {
        self.amount += 1;
    }
    [[AppDataObject sharedInstance].viewController.mathView updateMath];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
                         self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.980 green:0.404 blue:0.373 alpha:1];
                     }];
}
```

When I run this and continuously tap the object, it will log "Element Selected" once, then it wont log anything during the 0.2s animation, then it will once again log the message for every tap.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the docs on the UIView `animateWithDuration:animations:` methods:

> During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for
>   all views involved in the animation, regardless of the value in this
>   property. You can disable this behavior by specifying the
>   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option when configuring the
>   animation.

You need to use the long form animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:, and pass in an options value of UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction.

That should enable your view to handle touch events while it's animating. Note that if you execute an animation that moves a view it won't work correctly while animating because the view's position actually jumps to it's end position at the beginning of the animation, and then the appearance of the view moves to the end position during the rest of the animation duration.